# SQL Query to post process duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to be able to do this in SQL - although I'm not sure if it can because I don't know much SQL

Lets say I have a DB table(Rankings) with Fields:

> Id, Email, CreatedAt, Rank

I'd like to determine the number of records that are duplicates across the Email field but have varying ranks

I believe this should address the above query

```
Select Email, Count(Rank) 
From Rankings
Group By Rank
Having (Count(Rank)>1)
```

However then I'd like to take the rows of the above query and perform this additional operation on it:

Return the number of records who have the same Email but have varying Ranks in the earliest and latest CreatedAt field. Essentially I'd like to ignore the duplicate rows from the first query where the Rank did not change from the first record of the duplicate to the last record of the duplicate when sorted by time.

If this is complex, here's an example db

```
Id, Email, CreatedAt, Rank
1, a@xyz.com, 100, 4
2, b@xyz.com, 101, 1
3, c@xyz.com, 102, 5
4, d@xyz.com, 103, 5
5, c@xyz.com, 104, 2
6, d@xyz.com, 105, 3
7, d@xyz.com, 106, 5
```

The first query would return

```
c@xyz.com 2
d@xyz.com 3
```

I'd like the second query to return:

```
1
```

Because it would eliminate d@xyz.com who's ranking did not change over time, while c@xyz.com did

How do I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sounds to me like you are wanting to eliminate idle rankings, you could do this by adding a column and setting it to timestamp with a default setting of current time stamp, from there you just decide how long they need to be idle and run a query that column to find them WHERE column < time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Email, COUNT(DISTINCT Rank) AS variance 
FROM Rankings
GROUP BY Email
HAVING variance > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with a subquery:

```
Select
    Email,
    Ranks,
    substring_index(Ranks, ',', 1) as firstRank,  
    substring_index(Ranks, ',', -1) as LastRank
From (
    Select Email, Count(*), group_concat(Rank order by CreatedAt asc) as Ranks
    From Rankings
    Group By Email
    Having (Count(distinct Rank)>1)
) As varyingRanks
Having firstRank != LastRank
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the min and max createdat to compare the ranks at those specific times. You can do it by joining the original table twice and compare the ranks on those rows.

```
select count(*) --use * to see the values returned
from (Select Email, count(*) as cnt, min(createdat) as mn, max(createdat) as mx
      From Rankings
      Group By Email
      having count(*) > 1
      ) x
join rankings r1 on r1.email=x.email and r1.createdat = x.mn
join rankings r2 on r2.email=x.email and r2.createdat = x.mx
where r1.rank <> r2.rank
```